# Требуется ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Word пишет, что нужна запятая, но куда ее здесь "прилепить"?

> Документ храню по сей день.

Comment: А какое сообщение выдаёт Word? И если убрать звёздочки, это никак не влияет? (Лучше вообще убрать весь остальной текст, кроме этого предложения).

Answer (score 2):

Это простое предложение. Запятая не нужна. Для дальнейших уточнений советую обратиться в службу поддержки компании — поставщика программного обеспечения.

Comment: Чтобы обращаться к "поставщикам программного оборудования" нужно быть твердо уверенным, что ошибка их, а не моя. А я в этом не уверен.

Answer (score 0):

Виктор, вот Вам и говорят, что "прилепить" зпт абсолютно некуда. Как мы найдём для Вас правило о несуществующих знаках? К поставщикам! А лучше етого Ворда предать полному игнору.

Запятая *могла бы быть* **авторской**:

*храню, храню по сей день,*

то есть поработать уточнением к хранибельности, до трепета и головокружения,

но это маститому автору позволительно, простым смертным - ни-ни.